# How can I lighten vendor.js generated by webpack?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, package.json

I scanned the site I'm developing with Google LightHouse and got a warning "Remove unused JavaScript".
I am using Vue.js and building it with webpack. And I think vendor.js is generated from node_modules.
How can I make vendor.js lighter? I'm thinking that this could be done by excluding the external libraries written in package.json's devDependencies from vendor.js, is this the right and possible idea?

Also, if you have any other good ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to check what's inside your vendor.js, it's a library that allows you to analyze your bundle.

> This module will help you:
>
> - Realize what's really inside your bundle
> - Find out what modules make up the most of its size
> - Find modules that got there by mistake
> - Optimize it!

Comment: This sounds nice. I didn't know this. Thanks you!